# Why aren't Tappables spawning near me in Minecraft Earth?

Tags: minecraft-earth

Does the kind of area you play Minecraft Earth in affect Tappable spawns?

At home, in a residential area Tappables and adventures appear frequently and I can often collect them without leaving my house. When I am at work, however, no Tappables spawn near me - I can see Tappables in the distance but they're far out of reach.

Does the game recognize my residential home as a safe place to wander and will spawn Tappables there, and does it see the industrial district where I work as an unsafe place to roam and prohibits Tappables from spawning?

If not the area I work in, what else might explain why so few Tappables are near me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that some areas are blacklisted from spawning tappables due to safety reasons (and possibly other reasons). I've flown on several occasions and the only areas tappables will spawn at an airport seem to be within the confines of the terminal. I've also never seen tappables close to interstate highways.

EDIT:
From the MC Earth FAQ page (https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360033744412-Minecraft-Earth-FAQs):

> **CAN GAME PLAY LOCATIONS BE IN PLACES THAT MAY NOT BE SUITABLE?**
>
> Gameplay in Minecraft Earth is generated in locations that exist in
>   public places such as parks and open urban areas. Gameplay conditions
>   in any area can depend on many factors, time of day and surroundings,
>   amongst other things. We encourage our players to exercise caution and
>   to not play in potentially hazardous locations.
>
> If you find a game play location in a place that is not ideal for game
>   play, please go to http://aka.ms/mcearthsupport

It appears that at least one of the sources they use to determine what areas can generate tappables is Open Street Map:

> **HOW DO I GET MORE MINECRAFT EARTH GAMEPLAY LOCATIONS AROUND ME?**
>
> We use a variety of different inputs when we decide where to put
>   Minecraft Earth gameplay locations. One of the inputs we use is Open
>   Street Map data, which is a map built by the community of users. If
>   you’d like to see more gameplay locations around you, one of the best
>   things you can do is improve the accuracy of the Open Street Map data
>   in your area.
>
> In the future, we are exploring additional ways to get your input on
>   where you can play Minecraft Earth – stay tuned!

Comment: I'm gonna hold off on accepting the answer until I get concrete confirmation. That being said, I live about two blocks away from an interstate highway and I can confirm that tappables continue to spawn near it.

Comment: I added a link and a couple of quotes from the MCE FAQ. Doesn't prove for certain but I think it adds weight that it's area-based.